# Which venn diagram is described by $((A\cup B)\cap C^c)\cup (C\setminus (A\cup B))$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

Can some one help me figure out, which venn diagram is being described?

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I tried wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(not+C+and+(A+or+B))+or+(C+and+not+(A+or+B)) and it matches with the last one. But I am not an expert using wolfram.

Comment: Wolframalpha is correct in this case.  What is your question?

Comment: So the wolframalpha matches with the last option in the problem I asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is  $((A\cup B)\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus (A\cup B))=(A\cup B)\Delta C$ so it is the last one: all elements that are in $(A\cup B)$ but not in $C$ **or** all elements that are in $C$   but not in $(A\cup B)$

Comment: Yes :) Thanks.. i also answered the last option, so I were right :)

Comment: yes you are welcome.